# invalid character value for cast

Tags: java, sql, database, user-interface, ms-access

I keep on receiving this error, `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT data exception: invalid character value for cast`. I'm not sure how to fix it I have tried leaving out the primary key from my values part of my sql query, i'm not sure if the data is incompatible or if i am somehow declaring it wrong please help. I am trying to insert values from a GUI into an existing database.

Here is my code

```
    String racename, noofswimmers, avgtime, raceontime, tod, winid;
    racename = txtracename.getText();
    noofswimmers = txtnoswimmers.getText();
    avgtime = txtavgtime.getText();
    raceontime = txtraceontime.getText();
    tod = txttod.getText();
    winid = txtwinid.getText();
    
    
    
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Calvin/Documents/SwimGala.accdb");
        
        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into tblRace(RaceName,NoSwimmers,AvgTime,RaceOnTime,TimeOfDay,WinID)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(0,racename);
        pst.setString(1,noofswimmers);
        pst.setString(2,avgtime);
        pst.setString(3,raceontime);
        pst.setString(4,tod);
        pst.setString(5,winid);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record added");
        
        
                
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tabl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex);
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tabl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex);
    }
```

Comment: What are the values being passed to the `INSERT` statement parameters, and what are the datatypes of the corresponding columns in the table? It's possible you're trying to pass a value that can't be implicitly cast to the data type required for the column.

Comment: The values of the first row in the database are : RAC001, 6, 96.4, -1, 08:30:00, Tom2473. The datatypes of the columns are as follows in access: RaceName (Short Text), NoSwimmers(Number), AvgTime(Number), RaceOnTime(Yes/No), TimeOfDay(Date/Time), WinID(Short Text)

Comment: It's been years since I worked in Access so I can't offer an actual answer, but I know it's touchy about datetime data. Maybe try your code without the `TimeOfDay` column to see if that's the issue. If it is, you may want to write a new question that focuses on how to handle that specific input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert a `string` val into a numeric field.

You use a `setString` to set vals of the statement. The index for `setString` starts at `1`. You call `pst.setString(0, racename);`, you set the value at `0`, which is not existing.

This worked for me, change the index of `setStrings`:

```
// pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into tblRace(RaceName,NoSwimmers,AvgTime,RaceOnTime,TimeOfDay,WinID)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1,racename);
pst.setString(2,noofswimmers);
pst.setString(3,avgtime);
pst.setString(4,raceontime);
pst.setString(5,tod);
pst.setString(6,winid);
// pst.executeUpdate
```

You want to convert a `string` val to a `data` type that isn't compatible. You use the appropriate `set` for each parameter based on `data`.

`NoSwimmers` is of integer type, use `setInt` instead of `setString` to set value.

`setInt` set val of `NoSwimmers` after converting to an int using `parseInt`. Use the appropriate `set` for each parameter based on `data`.

---

This set the value corectly, and should fix the error.

##### Edit:

1. Check `data` type in the `database` table you are inserting vals into.

You see the datatype of the columns in the table.

```
RaceName (Short Text)
NoSwimmers(Number)
AvgTime(Number)
RaceOnTime(Yes/No)
TimeOfDay(Date/Time)
WinID(Short Text)
```

2. Check the `data` type of columns in table to ensure that the val is passed to the `INSERT` for each column.

This is trying to pass a val that is not casted to `data` type for columns.

We try to pass a `string` val to a column with a numeric `data` type. In the code the val is passed to `INSERT` parameters obtained from `GUI`.

**Be sure that the `data` of each val matches the `data` required for each column.**

3. The solution provided in the previous answer should be valid as it adresses the issue of using the wrong methods to set parameters.

In the code we see the `setString` is used to set parameter values for all columns. We should use the appropriate methods based on `data` type parameters.

We use `setInt` for `NoSwimmers`, `setDouble` for `AvgTime`, `setBoolean` for `RaceOnTime` and `setDate` for `TimeOfDay` - we can successfully pass the vals to columns.

Ensure that the `data` of vals is passed to `INSERT` params to match `data` for each column in the table, **use the appropriate set methods based on `data` types.**